Sens, syntaxe, dans « et non pas le hasard à son ombre de cette chose … » (Molloy, Samuel Beckett)
Tiré de Molloy, par Samuel Beckett
Juste avant la phrase contenant la partie en question

Il portait un
chapeau pointu, à ce qu’il me semblait. J’en fus frappé, il m’en
souvient, comme je ne l’aurais pas été par une casquette, par
exemple, ou par un melon. Je le regardai s’éloigner, gagné par son
inquiétude, enfin par une inquiétude qui n’était pas nécessairement
la sienne, mais dont il faisait en quelque sorte partie. C’était, qui sait,
mon inquiétude à moi qui le gagnait lui. Il ne m’avait pas vu. J’étais
juché au-dessus du niveau le plus élevé de la route et plaqué par-
dessus le marché contre un rocher de la même couleur que moi, je
veux dire gris. Qu’il aperçût le rocher, c’est probable. Il regardait
autour de lui, je l’ai déjà fait remarquer, comme pour graver dans sa
mémoire les caractéristiques du chemin, et il dut voir le rocher à
l’ombre duquel j’étais tapi, à la façon de Belacqua, ou de Sordello, je
ne me rappelle plus. Mais un homme, à plus forte raison moi, ça ne
fait pas exactement partie des caractéristiques d’un chemin, car.

La phrase, même paragraphe

Je veux dire que si par extraordinaire il doit un jour repasser par là,
après un long laps de temps, vaincu, ou pour chercher une chose
oubliée, ou pour brûler quelque chose, c’est le rocher qu’il cherchera
des yeux, et non pas le hasard à son ombre de cette chose
bougeante et fugitive qu’est la chair encore vivante.

Juste après la phrase, toujours le même paragraphe

Non, il ne me vit
certainement pas, pour les raisons que j’ai données et puis parce
qu’il n’avait pas la tête à cela, ce soir-là, pas la tête aux vivants, mais
plutôt à ce qui ne change pas de place, ou en change si lentement
qu’un enfant s’en moquerait, sans parler d’un vieillard. Quoi qu’il en
soit, je veux dire qu’il me vît ou qu’il ne me vît pas, je répète que je le
regardai s’éloigner, aux prises (moi) avec la tentation de me lever et
de le suivre, de le rejoindre même peut-être un jour, afin de mieux le
connaître, afin d’être moi-même moins seul.

Voilà une phrase qui me parait quasiment illisible en raison du fait que « chercher le hasard », à mon avis, ne peut pas avoir de sens ;  il est encore plus aberrant de parler de « l'ombre du hasard » ; il est quand même possible d'entrevoir ce que l'auteur aurait pu avoir  à l'esprit lorsqu'il a écrit ces lignes, mais il est facile de se tromper.  Il me semble que ce qui est dit serait quelque chose tel qu'exprimé dans l'interprétation ci-dessous (ce qui n'est pas totalement satisfaisant puisque il n'est pas clair qu'une idée soit ajoutée en précisant qu'il s'agit de chair encore vivante, ce qui s'appelle  plus normalement une silhouette humaine).
… c'est le rocher qu'il cherchera des yeux, et non pas l'ombre de cette chose
bougeante et fugitive qu’est la chair encore vivante que le hasard aura  jadis pu faire paraitre tout près
plus simplement
… c'est le rocher qu'il cherchera des yeux, et non pas l'ombre de cette silhouette humaine
bougeante et fugitive  que le hasard aura  jadis pu faire paraitre tout près
Selon l'avis du lecteur quelle autre interprétation pourrait être plus juste ? Est-ce que « chercher le hasard » pourrait encore être justifié ?

Je lis cette question à l'instant, j'y ferais en substance exactement la même réponse que pour l'autre question que tu as posé sur Molloy.  Envisages-tu de la fermer de toi-même ? Tu n'en es qu'au début de la trilogie mais si tu continues comme ça tu va reposer de multiples fois la même question...

@LPH L'extrait est beaucoup trop court, on manque cruellement de contexte. D'ailleurs en relisant les quelques phrases du dessus dans l'oeuvre originale, c'est beaucoup plus compréhensible.

@guillaume31 Pas de problème, j'ajoute quelques phrases (mais je ne crois pas que cela soit utile).

@LPH ben sinon on ne sait pas de quel rocher il s'agit, on ne sait pas que l'ombre en question est simplement celle du narrateur qui s'est caché, etc.

Quel est le fragment qui ne te plait pas? Peux-tu mettre en italiques ce qui ne te plait pas? Merci.

Seule la toute fin de l'extrait cité est sémantiquement embrouillée, quoique syntaxiquement correcte. Les mots "ombre" et "hasard" viennent à contretemps, comme trop impatients de se faire entendre. Remis en ordre, la phrase progresse dans une direction cohérente quoique par soubresauts:

C'est le rocher qu'il cherchera des yeux et non pas cette chose bougeante et fugitive qu’est la chair, [qui ne serait à nouveau tapie,]  encore vivante [dans ce futur si lointain et improbable,] à l'ombre
[de ce même rocher, que par] le hasard [le plus extraordinaire]."

J'ai mis entre crochets ce qui me paraît l'interpolation naturelle au vu de l'extrait cité. Le rocher est nécessairement celui

à l’ombre duquel j’étais tapi, à la façon de Belacqua, ou de Sordello

ainsi que le locuteur vient de le préciser, juste avant l'extrait cité; omettre cette partie du texte ne clarifie en rien le post, au contraire.
Ajouté après acceptation.
La question initiale est 100% pour fr.SE: que signifie la phrase de Beckett. Le reste, si enthousiasmant qu'il soit, est de la critique littéraire et non du français.
Je m'extasierais volontiers sur le génie de Beckett, la justesse avec laquelle il représente le processus mental du locuteur et l'intrusion intempestive des pensées, les collisions poétiques qu'engendre ce bouillonnement... c'est simplement hors sujet.
Deuxième ajout (inspiré par les commentaires de @None et @guillaume31).
Une autre lecture permet de laisser les mots dans l'ordre choisi par Beckett: il a conçu sa phrase à l'anglaise, faisant de "hasard" le COD complété par "la chair"; plutôt qu'un complément circonstanciel du groupe COD comme il serait naturel pour un Français.
En effet, "Hasard" signifie aussi circonstance fortuite, sur le renouvellement de laquelle il serait absurde de compter: ce hasard est celui qui amène présentement le locuteur à l'ombre du rocher et non celui proposé par ma 1ère interprétation: qui l'y ramènerait providentiellement lorsque le passant, dans un futur hypothétique aura besoin d'un point de repère.
Dans cette acception la phrase signifie, le style en moins:

C'est le rocher qu'il cherchera des yeux et non pas[, tapie par] hasard à son ombre[,] cette chose bougeante et fugitive qu’est la chair encore vivante.


Oui, mais "l'embrouille" dans le texte original est bien meilleure, elle supporte les idées d'ombre, de fugitif, de chercher des yeux quelque chose de pas clair, dont on se souvient à demi, qui n'était pas aussi nécessaire que la présence du rocher, mais plutôt quelque chose qui aurait pu être ou ne pas être là, au hasard.

@Frank Je ne vois pas le rapport avec fr.SE ni avec la question initiale, qui est de rendre intelligible la phrase de Beckett. Qu'elle soit un miracle stylistique ou juste pénible à lire est hors sujet.

Cette façon de penser aurait été  peut-être plus évidente dans Beckett s'il avait utilisé deux virgules (mais c'est encore discutable), une modification que je n'ai pas su voir (« et non pas le hasard,  à son ombre [celle du rocher] de cette chose bougeante et fugitive qu’est la chair encore vivante »). « Le hasard de [trouver] qqc en un certain endroit (ombre]» a un sens indéniable ; je ne pense pas que l'ellipse du verbe soit d'usage.  Il n'y a alors que peu à changer pour obtenir un sens. La phrase serait tout simplement difficile à lire (en raison peut-être d'une ellipse douteuse) ?

Je ne me représente pas du tout la scène comme toi, surtout dans l’interprétation du mot hasard ...

@FrançoisJurain C'est un commentaire sur le style, oui.

@FrançoisJurain Et en fait, on pourrait aussi dire que ce style renforce le sens.

@None une autre lecture possible serait: ... et non pas, [tapie] à son ombre par pur hasard, cette chose bougeante et fugitive [...], c-à-d: le hasard en question est celui par lequel le locuteur est aujourd'hui tapi, encore vivant, à l'ombre du rocher.

@FrançoisJurain je trouve qu'on s'éloigne un peu du texte avec le retricotage en "qui ne se serait tapie que par le hasard le plus extraordinaire" (si j'ai bien compris). Même si le sens est voisin, c'est bien "chercher le hasard" que Beckett choisit d'écrire, expression certes paradoxale mais c'est justement la raison pour laquelle l'homme cherche forcément autre chose.

Dans la mesure où tu donnes toi-même deux interprétations différentes du texte la logique aurait voulu que, non pas tu répondes à la question, mais que tu en demandes la fermeture comme  "Opinion-based". Les questions portant sur le style ne sont pas par contre un motif de fermeture (si bien sûr elles n'ont pas déjà été posées)

@None dans la mesure où une même interprétation sous-tend mes deux lectures, ma réponse n'a rien d'"opinion-based". D'autant que le choix de cette interprétation n'est pas affaire d'opinion, il est imposé par le texte: "Même comme simple point de repère à mémoriser, il est absurde de me préférer au rocher". Le problème énoncé par l'OP est de relier cette interprétation (forcée) à la formulation choisie par Beckett et il se trouve que je m'y reprends à deux fois avant d'y parvenir.

La lecture de Molloy ne se fait pas en passant par les canaux dits « traditionnels » de la grammaire et de la syntaxe, Beckett a placé le style au centre de son écriture et c'est comme ça qu'il faut le lire si on veut comprendre. Vouloir modifier ou rectifier Beckett c'est enlever sa substantifique moelle à son oeuvre, c'est en faire autre chose, ce n'est plus Beckett. À mon humble avis la question n'est pas de se demander ce que « l'auteur aurait pu avoir à l'esprit lorsqu'il a écrit ces lignes »  mais que reflète l'auteur de ce que le personnage a à l'esprit quand il transcrit ses pensées. Toute interprétation que chacun fait du texte est la bonne, c'est la tienne, c'est celle de celui qui lit et qui interprète les pensées du personnage au moment où il les lit. Pour moi, « le hasard » c'est « la part qu'il y a de hasard » et l'ombre, c'est l'ombre du rocher. Mais je ne m'attends pas à ce que quiconque comprenne comme moi car pas plus qu'un autre je ne peux pénétrer la pensée d'autrui, et surtout pas celle d'un personnage de Beckett.
Traduction en anglais que Beckett a fait de ce passage :

I mean if by some strange chance he were to pass that way again, after a long lapse of time, vanquished, or to look for some lost thing, or to destroy something, his eyes would search out the rock, not the haphazard in its shadow of that unstable fugitive thing, still living flesh...

the haphazard: on pourrait aller jusqu'à « désordre », « chaos » en français.
Une question quasi semblable, dans la mesure où la question porte sur le style de Beckett dans Molloy, a déjà été posée ; comme je ne veux pas me répéter, j'ai cherché à faire ici une réponse non personnelle car après tout je ne suis une autorité ni en stylistique ni en études beckettiennes. Donc qu'en disent des personnes plus qualifiées que moi ? J'ai donc cherché une autorité en la matière parmi les dizaines de critiques et commentaires sur Samuel Beckett facilement accessibles.
Voici quelques extraits d'un article de Sophie Milcent-Lawson, professeur de stylistique à l'Université de Lorraine :
L’indifférence méthodique : fragments d’une poétique énonciative dans Molloy¹

L’incipit de Molloy affiche d’emblée la rupture que Beckett entend établir avec les conventions narratives classiques. Le lecteur se trouve confronté à un anti-narrateur dont l’incompétence atteint tous les domaines de la narration. [...] Son incapacité à établir les faits avec exactitude est signalée par la formule récurrente « je ne sais pas », ignorance qui résulte à la fois de sa mémoire lacunaire [...] de ses confusions [...] Les traces de l’énonciation dans l’énoncé s’efforcent de créer le même effet d’improvisation maladroite [...] Enfin, le texte rend un compte scrupuleux de tous ses ratages et intègre délibérément les imperfections propres à l’état de brouillon, comme l’attestent les piétinements du discours  [...]


[...] En effet, ce qui ressort de l’examen du texte, c’est l’extrême
attention portée au langage par un locuteur qui se plaît à en
interroger le fonctionnement et les limites. Ses revendications
d’incompétence dans les domaines de la grammaire et du lexique (« J’ai
oublié l’orthographe aussi, et la moitié des mots. ») sont
démenties par l’habileté linguistique dont nombre de ses énoncés sont
la preuve. Les faiblesses affichées relèvent donc d’une posture. Mais
la nouveauté de ce roman ne se borne pas à l’invention d’un narrateur
qui feint indifférence et incompétence. Ce choix poétique et
énonciatif permet à l’auteur de se livrer, via son narrateur, à un
travail sur la langue qui s’inscrit dans un projet littéraire plus
vaste. Dans un texte contemporain de la rédaction de Molloy, Beckett
s’interroge ainsi sur les buts poursuivis par la peinture abstraite et
se demande ce qu’il reste « de représentable si l’essence de l’objet
est de se dérober à la représentation ». [...]


[...] Par ses choix énonciatifs, Molloy introduit un type nouveau de narrateur, qui se présente comme ne maîtrisant pas ou maîtrisant mal ses choix discursifs, de mauvaise volonté, contraint à la narration comme à un devoir de commande. Toutefois, l’indifférence ostensible de cet anti-narrateur ne doit pas occulter le fait que l’énonciation est désormais au centre du projet narratif. Le discours romanesque beckettien questionne ainsi systématiquement ce qui semblait aller de soi, tant au plan narratif (la présence d’un narrateur qui raconte avec compétence et efficacité) qu’au plan linguistique (un narrateur-locuteur maîtrisant le langage)². Cette mise en question des conditions qui rendent possible une littérature romanesque s’appuie sur un usage de la langue qui recherche les limites à la fois du langage et du sens, au risque de l’aporie³.

Et un extrait de la lettre de Beckett à son ami Axel Kaun (1937) :

It is to be hoped the time will come, thank God, in some circles it already has, when language is best used where it is most efficiently abused Since we cannot dismiss it all at once, at least we do not want to leave anything undone that may contribute to its disrepute. To drill one hole after another into it until that which lurks behind, be it something or nothing, starts seeping through – I cannot imagine a higher goal for today’s writer⁴.


 ¹Milcent-Lawson, Sophie. « L’indifférence méthodique : fragments d’une poétique énonciative dans Molloy ». La Prose de Samuel Beckett, édité par Julien Piat et Philippe Wahl, Presses universitaires de Lyon, 2013, https://doi.org/10.4000/books.pul.2861.
 ² C'est moi qui souligne.
³ Terme de logique : contradiction insoluble dans le raisonnement. 
 ⁴  Cited from : https://pitt.libguides.com/c.php?g=560810&p=3959279
The Letters of Samuel Beckett, Vol. 1 (1929-40), Edited by Martha Dow Fehsenfeld, Lois More Overbeck, George Craig, and Dan Gunn, Cambridge, Cambridge University Press, 2009, 518-20.

Bien vu. Une lecture, une personne seule. La mise en scène laisse, acteurs et actrices, la réinventer chaque soir. Partout : on attend Godot dans le désert… il arrive, Force du silence. Grains de sable, spectateurs actifs.

@Personne Oui, mais si on va vers un relativisme du sens, pourquoi l'auteur écrit-il? Est-ce uniquement pour fournir une trame sur laquelle chacun peut tisser les motifs qu'il veut?

@Frank … c'est un jeu. Il n'y a pas de volonté, Que du ressenti né d'une pensée mise en mot par l'auteur. Le même spectacle vivant n'est jamais le même à chaque représentation. La pensée vit alors spontanément au Présent, L'âme s'exprime derrière le masque. Elle vit le changement des ondes cosmos telluriques du Moment, L'être remet en cause son rôle en continu. L'esprit est clair, le souffle profond.


« chercher le hasard », à mon avis, ne peut pas avoir de sens

C'est exactement là que le narrateur veut en venir. C'est une manière de dire que c'est bien le rocher que l'homme cherche et pas la silhouette, puisque la présence de celle-ci relève de la pure chance.
Il est possible que Beckett ait choisi ces termes pour montrer la maladresse poétique du narrateur, même si ce n'est pas aussi flagrant que dans d'autres passages.
En tout cas, la réponse de @None a donné une clef de lecture primordiale. Il ne faut pas prendre les élucubrations du narrateur de manière trop rationnelle, au risque de se faire des noeuds au cerveau - et de saturer FLSE de questions ;)

Il y a quelque 130 000 questions sur l'ELU, et personne ne s'en plaint.  // Alors la présente question sera encore une de celles pour lesquelles on devra conclure qu'on ne sait pas, qu'on ne peut pas être trop sûr ;  en fait les cas d'incertitude sur sens et grammaire dans ce livre sont loin d'être aussi courants que certain le prétendent ; je trouve que ses phrases sont presque toujours parfaitement grammaticales et qu'elles ont suffisamment de sens. Ce que je signale ne semble être qu'un petit ensemble d'exceptions.

Samuel Beckett, prix Nobel, a interrogé l'inconscient —loin des démarches rationalistes —, celui dont on ne peut rien dire ni écrire… car son sens est caché, on le découvre “par hasard” quand on le cherche. Pour en saisir les difficultés, les entrevues de Kaushik : https://www.revue3emillenaire.com/blog/?s=Kaushik  … en commençant par les plus anciennes si l'on découvre ce domaine.

Ce n'est pas chercher le hasard, mais chercher le hasard de cette chose bougeante et fugitive.
